# Is it possible to use retrofit 1.9.0 and retrofit 2.x simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an app with a lot of existing Retrofit 1.9 interfaces. I'd like to begin
upgrading to Retrofit 2.x incrementally (all at once is not currently feasable)
to gain support for RxJava call adapters (and because 1.9 is no longer being developed).

It was fairly trivial to get Retrofit1's `RestAdapter` to share an OkHttp3 client
that would be used in the Retrofit2 interfaces. Version 1.9 and 2.x also have
different maven groupIds, so the classes can exist side by side with no issues.

However, I get the following exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonWriter(java.io.Writer)' is inaccessible to class 'retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonRequestBodyConverter'
```

Retrofit 1 has a hard dependency on GSON 2.3.1, The method in question was made public in GSON 2.4. I've set my Gradle dependencies so that the GSON dependency resolves to v2.7 (the latest version as I post this):

`build.gradle`

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0') {
    exclude module: 'gson'
}
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.1.0'

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0"
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Running `./gradlew :app:dependencies` indicates that GSON 2.7 is being resolved, however the runtime behavior is suspicious...

**Update:** I found that a 3rd party hardware SDK was bundling GSON 2.3.1 inside it's AAR. I can't figure out how to remove it though.

Comment: Why do you have to use both?

Comment: As explained in the first paragraph of the question:
* RxJava call adapter support
* 1.9 is no longer being developed

Comment: Yah I know. But you can migrate to Retrofit 2 for all. RxJava2 has released already. Even RxJav2-Retrofit2-Adapter https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

Comment: As also explained in the first paragraph, converting everything at once is not currently an option because of the size of the code already written in Retrofit 1.9. Incrementally adding new retrofit2 endpoints and converting old ones over time is what I need to be able to accomplish.

Comment: More than two years have been passed. Did you solve your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented `Retrofit 2.9.0` alongside `Retrofit 1.9` because of version 2's ability to handle sessions is much better and one of my API calls was failing because of the lack of handling response cookies(the session).

I have the same issue where migrating the entire project to Retrofit 2 is not feasible at this time. I can confirm that it is working though.

I will show you snippets of how I implemented both 1.9 and 2.9.0. See bottom for a link to the full class.

For both:
Create a class from which you can access your Retrofit object and call interfaces from:

```
public class ApiManager {

private static final String TAG = "API MANAGER";

private static final String API_URL = BuildConfig.API_URL;

private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    .setLenient()
    .create();

// The rest of the class to follow
```

and then specific to 1.9:

```
private static RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(ContextHandler.getContext());
        HashMap session = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
        Object session_id = session.get("session_id");
        Object token = session.get("token");

        if (session_id != null && token != null) {
            request.addHeader("Cookie", "session_id=" + session_id + ";");
            request.addHeader("Cookie", "token=" + token + ";");
            Log.i("INTERCEPT", "Sent Cookies");
        }
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }
};

public static OkHttpClient getClient() {

    // init okhttp 3 logger
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    JavaNetCookieJar jncj = new JavaNetCookieJar(CookieHandler.getDefault());


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    client.newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(ContextHandler.getContext()))
            .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(ContextHandler.getContext()))
            .addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
            .cookieJar(jncj)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    return client;
}

private static final RestAdapter REST_ADAPTER = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(API_URL) // On device
    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
    .setClient(new Ok3Client(getClient()))
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) //log the request
    .build();


public interface AuthenticationInterface {
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @POST("/auth/getsession")
    void Authenticate(@Body Authentication Auth, Callback<SessionStore> response);

    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @GET("/auth/logout")
    void logout(Callback<String> response);

    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @GET("/auth/logout")
    String logout();
}


// Bind REST_ADAPTER to Interface
public static final AuthenticationInterface AUTHENTICATION_INTERFACE = REST_ADAPTER.create(AuthenticationInterface.class);
// Use this when you want to run the request.
public static AuthenticationInterface getAuthenticationService(){ return AUTHENTICATION_INTERFACE;  }
```

So you would use the above as follows:

```
ApiManager.getAuthenticationService().Authenticate(auth, new Callback<SessionStore>() {

    @Override
    public void success(SessionStore sessionStore, Response response) {
        // Do somthing

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // Handle Error
    }
});
```

And for 2.9.0:

```
public static OkHttpClient getHeader() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(ContextHandler.getContext())) 
            .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(ContextHandler.getContext())) 
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = null;
                                Log.d("--Authorization-- ", "authorizationValue");

                            Request original = chain.request();
                            // Request customization: add request headers
                            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();


                            SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(ContextHandler.getContext());

                            HashMap session = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
                            Object session_id = session.get("session_id");
                            Object token = session.get("token");

                            if (session_id != null && token != null) {
                                requestBuilder.addHeader("Cookie", "session_id=" + session_id + ";");
                                requestBuilder.addHeader("Cookie", "token=" + token + ";");
                                Log.i("INTERCEPT", "Sent Cookies");
                            }
                            requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                                request = requestBuilder.build();

                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    })
            .build();
    return okClient;

}

private static final Retrofit REST_ADAPTER2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(API_URL) // On device
    .client(getHeader())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();

public interface JasperReportsInterface {

    /**
     *
     * @param agent_id
     * @param report_id
     */
    @retrofit2.http.Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @retrofit2.http.GET("/agents/{agent_id}/reports/{report_id}/")
    Call<Reports> GetAgentReportView(@retrofit2.http.Path("agent_id") String agent_id, @retrofit2.http.Path("report_id") String report_id);

    /**
     *
     * @param agent_id
     * @param report_id
     */
    @retrofit2.http.Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @retrofit2.http.GET("/agents/{agent_id}/reports/{report_id}/jobs")
    Call<Jobs> PollAgentReportData(@retrofit2.http.Path("agent_id") String agent_id, @retrofit2.http.Path("report_id") String report_id);

    /**
     *
     * @param agent_id
     * @param report_id
     * @param jsonBody
     */
    @retrofit2.http.Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @retrofit2.http.POST("/agents/{agent_id}/reports/{report_id}/jobs")
    Call<String> PostAgentReportData(@retrofit2.http.Path("agent_id") String agent_id, @retrofit2.http.Path("report_id") String report_id, @retrofit2.http.Body JsonObject jsonBody);

    /**
     *
     * @param agent_id
     * @param report_id
     * @param jsonBody
     */
    @retrofit2.http.Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @retrofit2.http.POST("/agents/{agent_id}/reports/{report_id}/jobs")
    Call<String> DownloadAgentReportData(@retrofit2.http.Path("agent_id") String agent_id, @retrofit2.http.Path("report_id") String report_id, @retrofit2.http.Body JsonObject jsonBody);




}
// Bind REST_ADAPTER2 to Interface
public static final JasperReportsInterface JASPER_REPORTS_INTERFACE = REST_ADAPTER2.create(JasperReportsInterface.class);
// Use this when you want to run the request.
public static JasperReportsInterface getJasperReportsService(){  return JASPER_REPORTS_INTERFACE;  }
```

And you would use the above as follows:

```
Call<Reports> reportsCall = ApiManager.getJasperReportsService().GetAgentReportView(agentsID, reportTypeID);
reportsCall.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Reports>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Reports> call, retrofit2.Response<Reports> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            report = response.body();

        } else {
            int statusCode = response.code();

            // handle request errors yourself
            ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Reports> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Dependencies you would need are the basic ones need for both 1.9 and 2 respectively.

See [here](https://pastebin.com/7bApJhzS) for full class.